# Keeping only data of the last 24 h in Database/FS

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, filesystems

I want to save/keep only data of the last 24 h in FS or in DB using SQLite. The saved data that is older than 24 h should automatically be deleted from data source. Is this possible and if yes how in c#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could define a trigger that deletes old data automatically.

Comment: if you want to do it auto, you cant use triggers, triggers are fired only when something happens to the database like delete, update or insert. no stored procedure in sqlite. your easy way would be to use a query in you up and run that based on some condition.

Comment: also be more specific about your question, tell about type of the app your building, is it a web based, window, mobile or what so ever.

Comment: Its a wpf windows application. And I hoped to find anything that can help me doing it auto.